# Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Are there the smallest Borel set containing $A$ or the largest Borel set contained in $A$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal B(X)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Fix $A \subset X$. Let
$$
A^* := \bigcap \{B \in \mathcal B(X) \mid A \subset B\} \quad \text{and} \quad A_* := \bigcup \{B \in \mathcal B(X) \mid B \subset A\}.
$$

Clearly,
$$
\mathring A \subset A_* \subset A \subset A^* \subset \overline A.
$$

If $A \in \mathcal B(X)$, then $A_* = A = A^*$. Now assume $A \notin \mathcal B(X)$, i.e., $A$ is not measurable. Can we prove that $A^*$ or $A_*$ is measurable?

The existence of non-measurable sets requires axiom of choice and is non-trivial. I can hardly come up with a simple example to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every singleton subset of $X$ is closed, hence is an element of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

So if $x\in A^{\complement}$  then $X-\{x\}$ is a Borel set with $A\subseteq X-\{x\}$ and consequently $x\notin A^*$.

This implies that $A=A^*$.

Dually it is also true that $A_*=A$.

Comment: So great. Your argument also shows that the result holds for any Hausdorff space.